# The result of getClass().getSimpleName() is different between android support and androidx when build apk with minifyenabled = true

Tags: android

The result of getClass().getSimpleName() is different between android support and androidx when build apk with minifyenabled = true.

In class CommentHolder, this statement below:

```
XLog.d("topic_adapter:" + getClass().getSimpleName());
if (getClass().getSimpleName().equals("CommentHolder")) {
   //todo
}
```

in android support the result is "CommentHolder", in androidx it's "f" or other ('a','b','c'..)

Who can tell me why？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you config the minifyenabled = true,the java class will be rename such as a.class,b.class when building, you should compare them with java api,not define a String variable. try this code below

```
 if (getClass().getSimpleName().equals(CommentHolder.class.getSimpleName())) {
  //todo
}
```

Comment: thanks @Emox i will try it later. now my question is `getclass().getSimpleName()` has different results will be produced under android support and androidx,  all used minifyenabled = true.

Comment: I tested it just now and the problem has been resolved. thanks @Emox